# Routing for following url edit/{item-name}/{desc}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to have following url:

```
www.example.com/item/edit/1/price
www.example.com/item/edit/1/description
```

where 1 is the item id, price and description is separate cshtml file

Is this possible to be done in asp.net mvc in controller file and routing? and how could it be done?

Comment: I don't think you can have the 'Price' and 'Description' as separate cshtml files.

Comment: let us know,why you are passing file names after Params.I thing that could be another parameter.

Comment: A good article about this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: price and description is a subset of the particular item. Therefore, it is more intuitive if the url is arrange in this way rather than edit/price/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attributing routing to do this, see here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx

So for the two paths you are requesting would be:

```
[RoutePrefix("item")]
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    // /item/edit/1/price
    // would result in invocation of
    // this method with itemid = 1 , desc = "price"
    [Route("edit/{itemid}/{desc}")]
    public ActionResult(int itemid, string desc) 
    {
        //code here
    }

}
```

Assuming you meant Id based off of the url provided, not sure exactly what this is for, but basically using attribute routing you can manipulate a url to resolve to pretty much any invocation of any controller method in MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using query strings as follows

First your routing will be something like

```
{action}/{Id}
```

Then you pass the cshtml name as a querystring parameter

Example call should be

```
www.abc.com/item/edit/1?page=description
```